# Rails and Cross Domain Cookies

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies

I am having a problem with ajax and cookies with rails. My current setup is as follows:

I have one application setup at domainfoo.com which is a Rails application and a static web page setup at domainbar.com that I want to communicate with domainfoo.com through ajax.

the domainfoo.com application is setup as follows:

application.rb

```
    before_filter :allow_cross_domain_access
    def allow_cross_domain_access
      response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
      response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "*"
    end
```

and the main part of the application (check_controller.rb):

```
    class CheckController < ApplicationController
      if cookies[:test]
        puts "cookie value: #{cookies[:test]}"
      else
        cookies[:test] = { :value => '123',
                           :domain => :all,
                           :path => "/check"
                          }
      end
     end
```

The route http://examplefoo.com/check maps to that controller. On the static page on domainbar.com I just have a simple jQuery ajax GET request that looks like:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $.get('http://domainfoo.com/check', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    });
```

When I view the network traffic in chrome I can see the cookie coming from the server, it gets set in the browers but then when I make the ajax request again the cookie never gets sent back to the server. I'm sure there is something that I am overlooking but I'm not sure what it is.